# My Nintendo Switch keeps kicking me out of Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On my Nintendo Switch, it keeps loading the Steve skin instead of developer steve. I have bedrock version 1.12.0. I cannot change my skin or go into any of my worlds, because that is when it crashes. When it crashes, it says "The software has been closed because an error occured" with no error code.

Comment: This happened to me when I played Paladins. I couldn't find anything online so I'd say your best bet is Nintendo Support

Comment: Thx Minecraft no longer crashes on me

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft for switch is currently on version 1.14.60 so you should try updating it as several updates have been bug fixes.

Saw that you said it worked, but it's a good idea to help prevent it from happening in future.